# Update component rendered data after async variable change React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm kind of new to React Native and am trying to render a `StackScreen` based on the value of a variable. The variable is filled `async` and should change from `something` to `null` which in return should show the `WelcomeStack` instead of the `HomeStack`. The problem is, React does not do anything after the variable changes from the `async` function.

The code:

```
// State.js
export const _getWelcomeComplete = async () => {
  let value;
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.getItem('welcomeComplete').then(
      (response) => (value = response),
    );
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
    console.log(error.message);
  }
  return value;
};

// App.js
export default function App() {
  let welcomed = 'something';
  _getWelcomeComplete().then((response) => {
    welcomed = response;
  });

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <WelcomeHeader />
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {welcomed === null ? (
          <Stack.Screen
            name="WelcomeStack"
            component={WelcomeStack}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
        ) : (
          <Stack.Screen
            name="HomeStack"
            component={HomeStack}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues in your code. The first one is, that you aren't using any state, which means React won't care about your changes and won't rerender the component. To solve this, use the `useState` hook to store the variable.

The second, less significant problem is that you are calling your `_getWelcomeComplete` function directly in the component body, so it would call on every rerender, creating an infinite loop. To solve it, put the call in `useEffect`, which executes it only when anything in the array in the second argument changes (in this case the array is empty, so it's called only on component mount)

Here's the modified code:

**App.js**

```
export default function App() {
  const [welcomed, setWelcomed] = useState('something');

  useEffect(() => {
    _getWelcomeComplete().then((response) => {
      setWelcomed(response);
    });
  }, [])

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <WelcomeHeader />
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {welcomed === null ? (
          <Stack.Screen
            name="WelcomeStack"
            component={WelcomeStack}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
        ) : (
          <Stack.Screen
            name="HomeStack"
            component={HomeStack}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Understanding hooks is very important in React, so here is a link to the offical docs: [Introducing Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)